# Where is libpq-fe.h on a Travis-CI instance?

Tags: postgresql, travis-ci

I'm trying to build a postgres database adapter (luapgsql) as part of my setup:

```
install:
  - sudo luarocks install --server=http://rocks.moonscript.org/dev luapgsql
```

But the build can't find `libpq-fe.h`:

```
Error: Could not find expected file libpq-fe.h, or libpq-fe.h for PQ --
you may have to install PQ in your system and/or pass PQ_DIR or
PQ_INCDIR to the luarocks command. Example: luarocks install luapgsql
PQ_DIR=/usr/local
```

I've tried what's suggested above, `apt-get install libpq-dev` and just `find \ -name libpq-fe.h`.  No luck so far.  Any ideas where it might be?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that running `pg_config` as part of the `install:` was the answer.  I could read the output in the log.

In the end, the line that worked for me for installing luapgsql on travis is:

```
sudo luarocks install --server=http://rocks.moonscript.org/dev luapgsql PQ_INCDIR=/usr/include/postgresql PQ_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```